# HTML Select Input Tag bringing error with "selected" attribute in React JS

Tags: html, reactjs, select, input, jsx

Seeing this warning in React
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on .
What does it connotes?

Comment: It simply says add `defaultValue` or `value` props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a warning that encourages you to change your code from doing `<option selected>` to doing `<select defaultValue="theValue">` or using a controlled select.

It's probably because React wants to keep consistency between the Form components.

Edit: you can probably implement it this way using `useState` hook and a controlled select:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("defaultValue");

...

<select value={value} onChange={(e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}}>
    <option value="defaultValue"> Default </option>
    <option value="otherValue"> Other </option>
</select>
```